# prevent radial-gradient from changing shape & size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a css3/js eyeball. It looks at your mouse pointer.

As can be seen here, it sort-of works http://jsfiddle.net/fsg3he2u/ (mouse into the preview box)

My main problem lies in the drawing of the `radial-gradient`.

`radial-gradient(at '+perX+'% '+perY+'%, #000 20%, #469B98 21%, #3083B7 30%, #306BB7 40%, #FFF 25%, #DE8888)` draws the gradient and allows movement, but the shape and size changes upon movement. Upon some searching I discovered `circle` attribute: 
`radial-gradient(circle at '+perX+'% '+perY+'%, #000 20%, #469B98 21%, #3083B7 30%, #306BB7 40%, #FFF 25%, #DE8888)` draws the gradient and allows movement, restricts the shape, but the size changes upon movement.

How can I prevent the size from changing? (I assume it's another attribute)

**Edit:** this looks pretty complete http://jsfiddle.net/fsg3he2u/23/ makes single or multiple eyes of any size (all same size)

**Edit 2:** I decided to continue extending this for multiple sizes and custom colours - http://jsfiddle.net/fsg3he2u/25/

Comment: i was already working in the direction that Rajkumar suggested, but wanted the eyeball easily resized by changing the `eyeballer` div dimensions. I ended up with this - http://jsfiddle.net/0cmjrt3t/

Comment: ...but then I **really** like the answer Jon suggested, and it is much easier to modify gradient stop points. So I came up with this - http://jsfiddle.net/fsg3he2u/21/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this in the fiddle and it worked well; just add a fixed size after your shape (150px looks pretty nice IMO).

```
 $("#eyeballer").css('background','radial-gradient(circle 150px at '+perX+'% '+perY+'%, #000 20%, #469B98 21%, #3083B7 30%, #306BB7 40%, #FFF 25%, #DE8888)');
    //var perXY = "( " + perX + ", " + perY + " )";
    //$("span:first").text("( perX, perY ) - " + perXY);
});
```

Comment: with some tweaking this proves a much better solution for a resizable eyeballer than what I was working on

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using percentages, use absolute values for gradient distances:
http://jsfiddle.net/tsr2b9jh/

```
$("#eyeballer").css('background','radial-gradient(circle at '+perX+'% '+perY+'%, #000 50px, #469B98 55px, #3083B7 80px, #306BB7 90px, #FFF 100px, #DE8888 120px)');
```

Comment: I was working in this direction but it proves rather messy if you want an easily resized eyeballer